# how can I get the label of a node´s content type, when already having the machine name of it?

Tags: php, drupal-8

As an example:
I have the machine name of the node bundle present. e.g "basic_page" and want to get the label of that bundle, in that example "Basic Page".

I can get that by loading a node of that bundle and then, geting its bundle and label like so:

```
node_load($nid)->type->entity->label();
```

but im searching for a more elegant, straight forward way without the need of loading the node.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the machine name, you should be able to use the [EntityTypeManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityTypeManagerInterface.php/interface/EntityTypeManagerInterface/8.8.x)

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('machine_name')->getLabel();
```